# CakePHP in a subdirectory using nginx (Rewrite rules?)

Tags: nginx, rewrite, cakephp

I managed to get this to work a while back, but on returning to the cakephp project I had started it seems that whatever changes I've made to nginx recently (or perhaps a recent update) have broken my rewrite rules.

Currently I have:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /basic_cake/ {
            index  index.php;

            if (-f $request_filename) {
              break;
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
              rewrite ^/basic_cake/(.+)$ /basic_cake/index.php?url=$1 last;
              break;
            }
        }

        location /cake_test/ {
            index  index.php;

            if (-f $request_filename) {
              break;
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
              rewrite ^/cake_test/(.+)$ /cake_test/index.php?url=$1 last;
              break;
            }
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen       8081;
        server_name  localhost;

        root /srv/http/html/xsp;

        location / {
            index  index.html index.htm index.aspx default.aspx;
        }

        location ~ \.(aspx|asmx|ashx|asax|ascx|soap|rem|axd|cs|config|dll)$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

}
```

The problem that I have is that the css and images will not load from the webroot. Instead if I visit http://localhost/basic_cake/css/cake.generic.css, I get a page which tells me:

> CakePHP: the rapid development php
>   framework Missing Controller
>
> Error: CssController could not be
>   found.
>
> Error: Create the class CssController
>   below in file:
>   app/controllers/css_controller.php
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this
>   error message, create
>   app/views/errors/missing_controller.ctp
>   CakePHP: the rapid development php
>   framework

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a workaround. Installed Apache and used a proxy_pass nginx directive to push the traffic from particular folders to Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your rewrite rules it should look like this

```
location / {
    root /home/public_html/sub.example.com/cake/app/webroot;
    index index.php;

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
        break;
    }
}
```

i had a similar problem and which was solved via this [cakephp & nginx config/rewrite rules](https://serverfault.com/questions/32070/cakephp-nginx-config-rewrite-rules)